# Error: Tried to register widget with id==class_level_grid but that id is already registered in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Hi I am getting a error while again selecting the drop down in DOJO

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

    function onReportTypesSelect()
    {
        if(getDijitValue('data_types') != 'Select')
            {

            if(getDijitValue('data_types') == 'class_level')
            {
                require([
                            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
                            "dojo/store/Memory",
                            "dojo/store/Cache",
                            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                            "dojo/query",
                            "dojo/domReady!"

                        ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query){
                            var userStore, dataStore, grid;
                            userStore = new Cache(JsonRest({target: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/data/classServlet"}), new Memory()); 
                            grid = new DataGrid({
                                id:"class_level_grid",
                                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: userStore}),
                                structure: [
                                            {name: 'Roll Number', field: 'roll', width: 'auto', defaultValue: ""},
                                             {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px', defaultValue: ""},
                                            {name: 'Class', field: 'class', width: '75px', defaultValue: ""}
                                ],
                            style:"font-family: calibri, Garamond, Comic Sans; font-size: 10;",
                            selectionMode:'single',  
                            autoHeight: 10,
                            rowsPerPage:40,
                            rowSelector:'20px',
                            selectable: true
                            }

                            , "class_level_grid_div"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
                            grid.startup();

                        });

            }
   if(getDijitValue('data_types') == 'class_level2')
            {
                require([
                            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
                            "dojo/store/Memory",
                            "dojo/store/Cache",
                            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                            "dojo/query",
                            "dojo/domReady!"

                        ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query){
                            var userStore, dataStore, grid;
                            userStore = new Cache(JsonRest({target: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/data/class2Servlet"}), new Memory()); 
                            grid = new DataGrid({
                                id:"class_level2_grid",
                                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: userStore}),
                                structure: [
                                            {name: 'Roll Number', field: 'roll', width: 'auto', defaultValue: ""},
                                             {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px', defaultValue: ""},
                                            {name: 'Class', field: 'class', width: '75px', defaultValue: ""}
                                ],
                            style:"font-family: calibri, Garamond, Comic Sans; font-size: 10;",
                            selectionMode:'single',  
                            autoHeight: 10,
                            rowsPerPage:40,
                            rowSelector:'20px',
                            selectable: true
                            }

                            , "class_level2_grid_div"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
                            grid.startup();

                        });

            }

    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>`enter code here`
    <body>
    <div id="data_types" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" style="width: 200px;" onchange="onReportTypesSelect()">
                         <span data-dojo-value="Select"><b>Select</b></span>
                        <span data-dojo-value="class_level"><b>class Level</b></span>
                        <span data-dojo-value="class_level2"><b>class Level</b></span>
    </div>
    <div id="class_level_grid_div" style="width: 95%; height: 90%;"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="class_level2_grid_div" style="width: 95%; height: 90%;"> </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Error is coming as Error: Tried to register widget with id==class_level_grid but that id is already registered.
when again selecting the drop down kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't populate grid above another grid without destroying the first one that you created.

so if you have grid with id=`MyGrid` placed at a div this div will be removed and the grid will replace it.

so you have to use two methods the `placeAt` and the `grid.destroyRecursive(true);`

the code below should work fine.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

    function onReportTypesSelect()
    {
        if(getDijitValue('data_types') != 'Select')
            {

            if(getDijitValue('data_types') == 'class_level')
            {
                require([
                            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
                            "dojo/store/Memory",
                            "dojo/store/Cache",
                            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                            "dojo/query",
                            "dijit/registry",
                            "dojo/domReady!"

                        ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query,registry){
                        //we are checking here if the grid with that ID already exists and if yes destroy it
                        if(typeof registry.byId("class_level_grid_div") != "undefined"){
                        registry.byId("class_level_grid_div").destroyRecursive();
                        }
                            var userStore, dataStore, grid;
                            userStore = new Cache(JsonRest({target: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/data/classServlet"}), new Memory()); 
                            grid = new DataGrid({
                                id:"class_level_grid",
                                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: userStore}),
                                structure: [
                                            {name: 'Roll Number', field: 'roll', width: 'auto', defaultValue: ""},
                                             {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px', defaultValue: ""},
                                            {name: 'Class', field: 'class', width: '75px', defaultValue: ""}
                                ],
                            style:"font-family: calibri, Garamond, Comic Sans; font-size: 10;",
                            selectionMode:'single',  
                            autoHeight: 10,
                            rowsPerPage:40,
                            rowSelector:'20px',
                            selectable: true
                            }).placeAt("class_level_grid_div"); // use the placeAt so you don't replace the dom
                            grid.startup();

                        });

            }
   if(getDijitValue('data_types') == 'class_level2')
            {
                require([
                            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
                            "dojo/store/Memory",
                            "dojo/store/Cache",
                            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                            "dojo/query",
                            "dijit/registry",
                            "dojo/domReady!"

                        ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query,registry){
                            var userStore, dataStore, grid;

                                if(typeof registry.byId("class_level2_grid_div") != "undefined"){
                        registry.byId("class_level2_grid_div").destroyRecursive();
                        }


                            userStore = new Cache(JsonRest({target: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/data/class2Servlet"}), new Memory()); 
                            grid = new DataGrid({
                                id:"class_level2_grid",
                                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: userStore}),
                                structure: [
                                            {name: 'Roll Number', field: 'roll', width: 'auto', defaultValue: ""},
                                             {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px', defaultValue: ""},
                                            {name: 'Class', field: 'class', width: '75px', defaultValue: ""}
                                ],
                            style:"font-family: calibri, Garamond, Comic Sans; font-size: 10;",
                            selectionMode:'single',  
                            autoHeight: 10,
                            rowsPerPage:40,
                            rowSelector:'20px',
                            selectable: true
                            }).placeAt("class_level2_grid_div"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
                            grid.startup();

                        });

            }

    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>`enter code here`
    <body>
    <div id="data_types" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" style="width: 200px;" onchange="onReportTypesSelect()">
                         <span data-dojo-value="Select"><b>Select</b></span>
                        <span data-dojo-value="class_level"><b>class Level</b></span>
                        <span data-dojo-value="class_level2"><b>class Level</b></span>
    </div>
    <div id="class_level_grid_div" style="width: 95%; height: 90%;"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="class_level2_grid_div" style="width: 95%; height: 90%;"> </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi @dori naji Thanks man it worked!!!!
I would like to add a correction it should be (class_level_grid) not (class_level_grid_div) while checking for registery..
 if(typeof registry.byId("class_level_grid") != "undefined"){
                        registry.byId("class_level_grid").destroyRecursive();
                        }

marking it as answered.. thanks once again